# I'd like to say that I liked Celtics more than I do Cleveland now. - Can I say like this?

Tags: sentence-construction

I was a huge fan of Boston Celtics when there were Big 3 on the team. They have disappeared and now I'm a fan of Cleveland. But I'd like to say that I liked Celtics more than I do Cleveland now. In this situation, these sentences are possible to use? Or is there any difference between them?

> 1. I used to be a bigger fan of Boston Celtics than I am of Cleveland now.
> 2. I'm not as big a fan of Cleveland as I used to be of Boston Celtics.

Comment: "I'm *more of a* Cleveland fan now" or  "Now I'm a bigger Cleveland fan  than a Celtics fan".  "Now" alone is sufficient to indicate the idea you're trying to convey with "used to be", though you could say "I'm a bigger Cleveland fan now than I used to be, now that the Celtics no longer have the Big 3".

Answer (score 1):

The first does not convey your being a Cleveland fan, I think.  If you consider that Cleveland is your favorite team now, then you ought to specify that.  It doesn't really have to be a single sentence, perhaps.  Or you can use the semicolon to separate two parts if you feel there needs to be a single full stop.  Or something like

> I was a huge fan of Celtics in the past, and now I like Cleveland, but not nearly as much.

As to the difference between the two sentences, the second one appears to explain that you actually *are* a fan of Cleveland, yet some tone of exclusivity of your team preference is lacking...